# How to turn a distance matrix into a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

We coded a way to turn audio files into spectrograms and then made a distance matrix of those spectrograms in order to be able to know the dissimilarity between every audio files but the problem is that we don't know how to determine how to associate the distances we got to which file it was , Can someone tell us ?
In addition to that we thought that it would be easier to work with a dictionary of the distances with the keys as the filename and the values as the distance but we don't know how to obtain this dictionary can someone help us ?

we already tried to obtain a dictionary but it doesn't work and we tried to execute the full_distance_matrix function only comparing one file then two files then  three and still didn't find which files correspond to which distance. Furthermore our biggest problem is that we haven't been able to make a dictionary out of the distance matrix that we have after executing the program with containing the files.

here is the function we use to obtain our distance matrix:

```py
def full_distance_matrix(ls, dtw_func=dfw, method=euclidean, n_jobs=-1, weight=1.):
    """
    Provided a list of arrays ls, computes pairwise distances between the elements of ls.
    """
    assert len(set([_.ndim for _ in ls])) == 1, 'Elements should all have the same number of dimensions'
    assert len(set([_.shape[-1] for _ in ls])) == 1, 'Elements of ls must have the same size in the last axis'

    with Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs) as par:
        results = par(delayed(dtw_func)(ls[i], ls[j], method=method, weight=weight)
            for i in range(1, len(ls))
                for j in range(i))
        #print(results)
    results = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(results)
    return results
```

Comment: Do you have the filenames corresponding to the arrays in `ls`?